# How to prevent sending message after reconnect in ejabberd

Tags: erlang, xmpp, ejabberd

Suppose we have client `A` and client `B`.

client `A` has connection to jabber.
client `B` has no connection to jabber.

client `A` sends "hello" message to `B`. when client `B` reconnected to `ejabberd` will receive "hello" message.

i want client `B` only receive "hello" message when it connected to `ejabberd`.

i commented `mod_offline` module in ejabbed config file, but didn't solve problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you comment mod_offline, then messages sent to offline users are not stored, they are lost.

If client B logins with negative priority, it does not receive offline messages. Later when the client sets a positive priority, it receives all the offline messages.

Comment: When client B logins with negative priority, client A can't send message and receive `service-unavailable`

Comment: If you disable mod_offline, obviously ejabberd will reject messages sent to offline users, and will return an error service-unavailable.